# Sencha Touch: Nested list scrolls to top on Back, how can I disable this?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a working nested list.
When I navigate back by click the back button, it correctly loads the previous list BUT the default seems to scroll it to the top.

It's annoying because say I click on list item #50 and click back, it should show the list positioned back at the position where I was (at item 50) not be scrolled up at item 1. It forces me to scroll down all the way to item 50 to continue exploring where I was.

So is there a way to cancel the "scroll-to-top-on-back" behavior of the nested list? Any way to hack this in the code appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could use method [`scrollToRecord()`](https://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-method-scrollToRecord) method for your list on [`back`](https://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList-event-back) event in [`NestedList`](https://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList). Like this

```
lastActiveList.scrollToRecord(node)
```

---

**Another way**

You could set previous scroll position by using [`getScrollable()`](https://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList-method-getScrollable). You need to use [`itemtap`](https://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList-event-itemtap) and [`back`](https://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList-event-back) events on [`NestedList`](https://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList).

- On `itemtap` you get get current scroll position and set into your current active list

  ```
  list.yPosition = list.getScrollable().getScroller().position.y;
  ```
- And on back button you can again set the same previous scroll position to your list.

  ```
  lastActiveList.getScrollable().getScroller().scrollTo(0, lastActiveList.yPosition);
  ```

You can check with working **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2l4k)**

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',

    launch: function() {

        Ext.define('ListItem', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            config: {
                fields: ['text']
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            model: 'ListItem',

            storeId: 'listItemStore',

            defaultRootProperty: 'items',
            root: {
                items: items
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.NestedList', {

            fullscreen: true,

            store: 'listItemStore',

            listeners: {

                itemtap: function(tree, list, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
                    list.yPosition = list.getScrollable().getScroller().position.y;
                },

                back: function(btn, node, lastActiveList) {
                    lastActiveList.getScrollable().getScroller().scrollTo(0, lastActiveList.yPosition);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, however the fiddle you provided does not return to position if I navigate more than one level

Comment: I have updated my answer  and you can check it on **[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2l4k)**

Comment: If I click 27, then click first element then click first element then back then back, It should be at 27, however the list is at 1

Comment: still same problem, it remembers only one level deep

Comment: I have checked with same 27 and I also create one more level and go there again back main list but same on 27. You can open your console i have log there scroll position for all deep level

Comment: works on Chrome-Mac, but not Safari-Mac. Numbers in console are ok in both browsers, so it seems to be Safari that don't want to scroll for n obscure reason. I emptied the cache on Saf to be sure to have latest code, but does not change anything